# Spacy - Intepret text with stripped accents

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am working with spacy to analyze some text in french.

Somehow, in my data, all accented characters have been replaced by their non accented equivalents (ex: réserve --> reserve).

Hence, when I try to tokenize my strings and retrieve lemmas, spacy fails to identify my non accented terms.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('fr')

doc_accented = u'réserve moi une chambre'
[token.lemma_ for token in nlp_test(doc_accented) if token.is_punct==False and token.is_space==False and token.is_stop==False]
# Returns : [u'réserver', u'chambrer']

doc_not_accented = u'reserve moi une chambre'
[token.lemma_ for token in nlp_test(doc_not_accented) if token.is_punct==False and token.is_space==False and token.is_stop==False]
# Returns : [u'reserve', u'chambrer']
```

I tried to add new entries to the vocabulary by removing all accents from the existing entries and copying their attributes.

```
import unicodedata

def strip_accents(s):
    return ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')

attr_list = ['a list of attributes']

for el in nlp.vocab.strings:
     normalized_str = strip_accents(el)
     lexeme = nlp_test.vocab[normalized_str]

     for attr in attr_list:
         setattr(lexeme, attr, getattr(nlp.vocab[el], attr))
```

Do you know if there is a way to edit the vocabulary such as `u'reserve` can be interpreted by spacy as `u'réserve'` ?

Xavier

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem, have you found any solution ? Thanks

Comment: Nope, I gave up on it :/